# How do I make R Shiny react to slider changes, but not recalculate everything if I want to plot another part of solution

Tags: r, plot, shiny, reactive

I am new to shiny (and just joined the Stack Overflow, so apologies if I'm not following all etiquette rules yet :) ), and although I have managed to get my code working, there is something that I just cannot get my head around. Below is a code that solves a system of two differential equations, with coefficients being selected using Shiny sliders, and in the main panel I am trying to select which of the two variables to plot. The problem is that since selection of the plotting variable is part of the "input", if I change a variable that I want to plot, this results in the recalculation of the whole thing. I have attached a short code illustrating this problem on the example of a small system, but in reality I have a really large system of ODEs that takes quite a lot of time to solve, so I really need to make sure that if the sliders with parameters are not changed, the system is only solved once, and I can then separately plot each of the variables without a time-consuming recalculation of the whole thing.

I have had a look at "reactive" as an option, but can't see how to make it work for this. Could you please have a look at the short code below and let me know if that's possible, and more specifically, how to make it plot either U or V but without solving the system again.

Thanks a lot in advance!

```
library(deSolve)
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(plotly)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fluidRow(
        column(width=6,
               sliderInput("a", "Coef 1",0, 5, 1, step=0.2),
               sliderInput("b", "Coef 2", 0, 5, 1, step=0.2)
        )
      )
    ),
    mainPanel(
      selectInput("Var",
                  label = "Choose variable to plot:",
                  choices = c("First"="U", "Second"="V"), 
                  selected = c("U")
                  ),

      plotlyOutput("plot0")

    )
  )
)

LV=function(t,y,p){ # define Lotka-Volterra system
  with(as.list(p),{
    z=rep(0,2)
    z[1]=y[1]-a*y[1]*y[2]
    z[2]=b*y[1]*y[2]-y[2]

  return(list(z))
})
}

Run_LV=function(p){ # run the simmulation
t = seq(from=0, to=10, by=0.1)
y0=c(1.5,0.7) # initial condition
para=c(list("a"=p$a,"b"=p$b)) # values of parameters

out = ode(y=y0, times=t, func=LV, parms=para ,method="ode45")

return(list("out"=out))
}

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$plot0=renderPlot({

  sim=Run_LV(input)

   sol=sim$out
   xvar=sol[,1] # time
   if(input$Var=="U"){
     yvar=sol[,2] # will plot U component
   }else{
     yvar=sol[,3] # will plot V component
   }

   data<- data.frame(xvar,yvar)
   p=plot_ly(data,x=~xvar, y=~yvar, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines')
   p

  })

}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: `reactive` is the right way to do this, the calculations are then cached if no input is changed, so it does not always recalculate

Comment: @tpetzoldt Thanks for getting back to me on this. I have tried to make it reactive by writing `sim=reactive({Run_LV(input)})` but it returns an error message "Error in $: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable" Any idea what I could be doing wrong? I've also tried `sim=reactive({as.data.frame(Run_LV(input))})` but get the same error

Comment: You need to run the reactive statement as a function with parentheses, i.e. `sim()`. See `simulate()` in my example below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here one of my Lotka-Volterra teaching apps implemented as Markdown document. I hope that it can serve as an example:

````
---
title: "Resource Dependent Lotka Volterra Model"
output: html_document
runtime: shiny
---


```{r, echo=FALSE}
suppressMessages(library(deSolve))

lv <- function (t, x, parms) {
  with(as.list(c(x, parms)),{
    ds <- s_in - b * s * p + g * k + pulse(t, s_start, s_duration, s_pulse)
    dp <- c * s * p - d * k * p
    dk <- e * p * k - f * k
    list(c(ds, dp, dk))
  })
}
#parms  <- c(s_in=0, b=0, c=0.1, d=0.1, e=0.1, f=0.1, g=0, s_start=0, s_duration=0, s_pulse=0)
times  <- seq(0, 200, by=0.2)
#init   <- c(s=1, p=1, k=0.5)

pulse <- function(t, s_start, s_duration, h_pulse) {
  if ((s_start <= t) & (t < (s_start + s_duration))) h_pulse else 0
} 
```


```{r, echo = FALSE, }
simulate <- reactive({
  parms  <- c(s_in=input$s_in,
              b=input$b, c=input$c, d=input$d, e=input$e, f=input$f, g=input$g,
              s_start=input$s_start, s_duration=input$s_duration, s_pulse=input$s_pulse)

  init <- c(s=input$S0, p=input$P0, k=input$K0)
  ode(init, times, lv, parms, method="adams")
})
```


```{r, echo=FALSE}
renderPlot({
  #print(system.time(
    res <- simulate()
  #))
  par(lwd=2)
  par(las=1)
  par(cex.axis=1.4)
  layout(matrix(c(1,2), nrow=1, byrow=TRUE), widths=c(2, 1))
  matplot(res[,1], res[,2:4], type="l", xlab="time", col=c("black", "forestgreen", "red"), lwd=3, ylab="state variables")
  legend("topright", legend=c("S", "P", "K"), col=c("black", "forestgreen", "red"), lwd=3, lty=1:3, cex=1.4)
   plot(res[,3], res[,4], type="l", xlab="P", ylab="K")
})
```

<small>
```{r, echo=FALSE}
inputPanel(flowLayout(
  h4("Initial values:"),
  numericInput(
  "S0", label = "S0: Substrate", value = 1.0, min = 0, max = 2, step = 0.1
  ),
  numericInput(
  "P0", label = "P0: Producer", value = 1.0, min = 0, max = 2, step = 0.1
  ),
  numericInput(
  "K0", label = "K0: Consumer", value = 0.5, min = 0, max = 2, step = 0.1
  )),
  flowLayout(
  h4("Model parameters:"),
  numericInput(
  "b", label = "b: substrate utilisation", value = 0.0, min = 0, max = 1, step = 0.01
  ),
  numericInput(
  "c", label = "c: producer growth", value = 0.1, min = 0, max = 1, step = 0.1
  ),

  numericInput(
  "d", label = "d: predation loss", value = 0.1, min = 0, max = 1, step = 0.1
  ),

  numericInput(
  "e", label = "e: consumer growth", value = 0.1, min = 0, max = 1, step = 0.1
  ),

  numericInput(
  "f", label = "f: consumer mortality", value = 0.1, min = 0, max = 1, step = 0.1
  ),
  numericInput(
  "g", label = "g: substrate recycling", value = 0.0, min = 0, max = 1, step = 0.01
  )),
  flowLayout(
  h4("Substrate import:"),
  numericInput(
   "s_in", label = "S_in (import baselevel)", value = 0.0, min = 0, max = 1, step = 0.01
  ),
  sliderInput(
    "s_pulse", label = "s_pulse (pulse height):", min = 0.0, max = 1.0, value = 0, step = 0.1
  ),
  sliderInput(
    "s_start", label = "s_start (time of pulse):",min = 0.0, max = max(times), value = 10, step = 1
  ),
  sliderInput(
    "s_duration", label = "s_duration (duration):", min = 0.0, max = 5, value = 1, step = 0.1
  )
), textsize="50%")
```
</small>

### 3D State diagram

```{r, echo=FALSE}
library(scatterplot3d)
renderPlot({
  res <- simulate()
  scatterplot3d(res[,2], res[,3], res[,4], type="l", xlab="S", ylab="P", zlab="K", color="red", lwd=2)
}, width=600, height=400)
```
````

Comment: Thanks for the flowers, so you may consider to accept the answer?

Comment: Sorry, didn't know that thing existed :), I've just accepted the answer. I have done what you suggested for my own code, it works perfectly, once again thanks a lot for your help.